# Does log4net AdoNetAppender support sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, log4net

My config file below: very strange,I have spent a day to find out where I am wrong, but still not working, it still not log anything in the database，but I can output them using RollingFileAppender. Also, the store procedure WriteLog is working well.(I have tested it using sql server studio). I have tried to change the connectionType but not working. 
Unfortunately I don't have sql server 2000/2005 to test, my log4net version should be the latest one: log4net 1.2.10.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
      <appender name="AdoNetAppender_SqlServer" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
        <!--<threshold value="OFF" />-->
        <bufferSize value="1" />
        <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <!--<connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />-->
        <connectionString value="Data Source=.\MSSQLSERVER2008,2222;Initial Catalog=UnleashedSaaS;User ID=sa;Password=dogblack;" />
        <commandType value="StoredProcedure" />
        <commandText value="WriteLog" />
        <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%date{yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff}" />
            </parameter>
      <parameter>
                <parameterName value="@thread" />
                <dbType value="String" />
                <size value="255" />
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%thread" />
            </parameter>
      <parameter>
                <parameterName value="@log_level" />
                <dbType value="String" />
                <size value="50" />
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%level" />
            </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logger" />
                  <dbType value="String" />
                  <size value="255" />
                  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%logger" />
            </parameter>
      <parameter>
              <parameterName value="@message" />
              <dbType value="String" />
              <size value="4000" />
              <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%message" />
            </parameter>
         <parameter>
             <parameterName value="@exception" />
             <dbType value="String" />
             <size value="4000" />
             <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
         </parameter>
      </appender>
      <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
        <!--<threshold value="OFF" />-->
        <file value="LogData\\" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <datePattern value="ul_yyyy-MM-dd.LOG" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <rollingStyle value="Date" />
        <maximumFileSize value="2MB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="false" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %p %u %c %l %m %n%n%n" />
        </layout>
      </appender>
      <root>
        <level value="ALL"/>
        <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender_SqlServer" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
      </root>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to determine what is going wrong is to use [dbgview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) from Sysinternals. If the logging fails you will probably see error messages appearing there.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have found the problem, it is because "<connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />" i have double output "System.Data, System.Data", the log4net does work for sql server 2008, thank you again!